# Iterating Through Table with Pagination in Tosca

Tags: automation, tosca

I'm working on an automation script for a large table with pagination. Each table row contains a 'View' button, and upon clicking it, it navigates to the 'Result Details' page. On this page, there's another button that, when clicked, initiates the download of a PDF. So I want to create a script if I run all the results pdf downloaded. I'm facing challenges looping through the table across paginations. Can someone provide guidance on how to address this issue?
Table example :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ5Yk.png)

I've developed a module that scans the application and executes the 'View' button click operation. Now, I aim to run it through a loop for every row in that table.